# Heroku cannot detect my node buildpack for app, but when setting buildpack in cli it says the heroku/nodejs is already set up on app?

Tags: html, css, node.js, heroku, sass

I have tried deploying app through heroku through cli and through linking git repo, through the git repo I am now getting

```
!     Warning: Multiple default buildpacks reported the ability to handle this app. The first buildpack in the list below will be used.
            Detected build packs: Python, Node.js
```

However, when I try to uninstall python build pack as explained here (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) it says it can't be detected. When I try to install Node build pack it says it cannot be detected. But when I press deploy branch it runs the python pack since it is apparently the first build pack in the list.

I have tried making a requirement.txt file as noted in other answers but that took me from error in the post title to the error listed above with multiple packs

Comment: What buildpacks are currently listed for the app? (https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/[app-name]/settings)

Comment: heroku/node.js , its a simple page of just html css js and sass installed with node